# beginner python issue: pyodbc connection

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pyodbc, mdf

beginner python programmer here,

I'm having an issue with pyodbc. I've included two images. The first is the code itself... and here it is again in text:

```
def retrieve_db(self):

    conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=Students;Trusted_Connection=yes;')

    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tbl_student")

    for row in cursor:
        print(row)
```

The issue is that I have an .mdf that I'm trying to connect to but when I execute the program to retrieve all records it does not connect. Really not sure what the issue is. Reading other posts across the web I believe it's something to do with the connection string itself but I can't figure out how to syntax the correct param. The pyodbc connector was installed correctly as far as I'm aware.

Can anyone help? In particular does anyone know how to create and connect to  an.mdf using Visual Studio and the python pyodbc? Also, when I attempt to connect to a local DB created in MySQL workbench, I get the same issue. Any suggestions?

[code in editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIInG.png)

[the .mdf using the built in sql server on Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwPk9.png)

[the error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2j4Ln.png)

Comment: can you show us the error?

Comment: no compile error. it just does not output anything from the mdf.

Comment: actually it does: i added the error image to the original post. new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score -1):

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=Students;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
```

According to your code you're trying to use "SQL Server" driver. Is ODBC Driver for SQL Server properly installed on your system?

If not, please, download it from Microsoft website and install.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: yeah i downloaded it directly from ms. it's the weirdest thing. installed it using the pip installer and confirmed that it is installed. it just won't output sql data. >.<